# Implementing a filter in play framework IN JAVA

Tags: playframework

I copied the SimpleLoggingFilter example filter here:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters

I renamed it and put it in the package filters, and attempted to load it in my app by changing application.conf as follows:

```
play.http {
...
filters = filters.SimpleLoggingFilter
...
}
```

I saw somewhere that I needed to also modify build.sbt, so I added this:

```
libraryDependencies += filters
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
play.http.filters [class java.lang.Class}] does not implement interface play.api.http.HttpFilters or interface play.http.HttpFilters.
```

What did I do wrong?